# How can I submit different PRs from different branches while submitting only the relevant changes?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to Git, and currently working on different features, where for each feature I create a new branch and start working on it. But many times, after I finished working on a feature, submit a PR, and then create a new branch to work on a second feature - then when I submit the second feature from that second branch, I will also submit the changes from the previous feature.

It happens automatically, I even tried to not stage the irrelevant files, by using git reset.
Those irrelevant files from the previous feature don't show as committed, yet in the PR they are submitted. So in every PR I end up submitting the changes from the previous PR.

Please note: I'm referring to submitting a few PRs consecutively which weren't merged yet, and each feature is independent from the other one

What am I doing wrong in this workflow and what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: No they are independent from each other

Comment: It sounds like you're creating new feature branches from the existing feature branches, rather than from the target branch.

Answer (score 1):

### If it's necessary to stack the second feature on the first...

Then you'd do just as you have been (minus the reset rigmarole). Your PRs should be merged in sequence, so the diff from the first gets nullified before the second PR is encountered. Thus, only the diff from the second feature ultimately gets merged with the second PR.

### Otherwise...

You should be creating your feature branches from the main (PR target) branch, not from an earlier feature branch. By doing so you completely eliminate the problem you're having. As the main branch is updated, merge it back into your feature branch to keep it updated.